# Object Oriented Design for Checkers and Tic Tac Toe

Tags: java, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I layed out the similarities between the two games with the intention of possibly extending it to chess but questioning my design.

Similarities

- Piece - location of the item (row, col) on board
- Board - nxn grid of Pieces
- Game - contains a Board, and list of players
- Player - name of player

Differences

- In checkers you can move in different directions so I created a separate abstract class called Checker that inherits from Piece and implements a interface Moveable which returns the pieces moves. So Pawn and King must implement this method and provide its moves.

Issues and Concerns

- I am questioning this design because I could have also created an abstract method vs an interface but this would not be extendable to chess.
- I also did not know how to relate a player to a marker such as x or o in tic tac toe. I use a hashmap to map a player to its marker.
- I have some code duplication for checkers in which I have an enum color but I also have a variable marker which is kinda the same thing. Not sure how to remedy this.
- Is it ok to typecast an object? Since board doesn't know what type of piece it has, I have to do this in the Checkers class

```java
List<List<Integer>> moves = ((Checker)piece).getPossibleMoves();
```

Notes

I don't have all the implementation complete such as knowing when a player won, or handling edge cases or when a pawn turns into a king. I also hard coded the players for the meantime for simplicity, just want feedback if this is a good direction.

```java
public class Piece {
    private String marker;
    protected int row;
    protected int col;

    public Piece(String marker, int row, int col) {
        this.marker = marker;
        this.col = col;
        this.row = row;
    }

    public String getMarker() {
        return marker;
    }

    public void setMarker(String marker) {
        this.marker = marker;
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public void setRow(int row) {
        this.row = row;
    }

    public int getCol() {
        return col;
    }

    public void setCol(int col) {
        this.col = col;
    }
}

public class Player {
    private String name;

    public Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Board {
    private Piece[][] grid;

    public Board(int rows, int cols) {
        grid = new Piece[rows][cols];
    }

    private boolean isSpotEmpty(int row, int col) {
        return grid[row][col] == null;
    }

    public void move(Piece piece) {
        if(isSpotEmpty(piece.getRow(), piece.getCol())) {
            grid[piece.getRow()][piece.getCol()] = piece;
        } else {
            throw new InvalidStateException("Invalid Move");
        }
    }

    public void showBoard() {
        for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++) {
                Piece piece = grid[i][j];
                if(piece == null) {
                    System.out.print('*');
                } else {
                    System.out.print(piece.getMarker());
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public boolean isCellEmpty(int row, int col) {
        return grid[row][col] == null;
    }

    public String getMarker(int row, int col) {
        return grid[row][col].getMarker();
    }

    public Piece getPiece(int row, int col) {
        return grid[row][col];
    }

    public void removePiece(int row, int col) {
        grid[row][col] = null;
    }
}

public abstract class Game {
    protected List<Player> players;
    protected Board board;
    public abstract void startGame();
    public abstract Piece getPieceFromInput(Player player, String marker);
}
```

Here is Tic Tac Toe

```java
public class TicTacToe extends Game {
    private static final int BOARD_SIZE = 3;
    private HashMap<Player, String> playerMap;

    public TicTacToe() {
        board = new Board(BOARD_SIZE, BOARD_SIZE);
        players = new ArrayList<>();
        players.add(new Player("player1"));
        players.add(new Player("player2"));
        playerMap.put(players.get(0), "o");
        playerMap.put(players.get(1), "x");
    }

    @Override
    public void startGame() {
        boolean playerOneTurn = true;
        Player currPlayer;
        Piece piece;
        while(1 < 2) {

            currPlayer = (playerOneTurn) ? players.get(0) : players.get(1);
            piece = getPieceFromInput(currPlayer, playerMap.get(currPlayer));
            try {
                board.move(piece);
                playerOneTurn = !playerOneTurn;
            } catch(InvalidStateException e) {
                System.out.println(currPlayer.getName() + e.getMessage());
            }
            board.showBoard();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Piece getPieceFromInput(Player player, String marker) {
        System.out.println(player.getName() + " Please enter move by row col");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int row = sc.nextInt();
        int col = sc.nextInt();
        return new Piece(marker, row, col);
     }


}
```

Here is Checkers

```java
public abstract class Checker extends Piece implements Movable {
    protected Color color;

    public Checker(String marker, int row, int col, Color color) {
        super(marker, row, col);
        this.color = color;
    }

}

public enum Color {
    RED, BLACK
}

public class King extends Checker {

    public King(String marker, int row, int col, Color color) {
        super(marker, row, col, color);
    }

    @Override
    public List<List<Integer>> getPossibleMoves() {
        List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        //go up/down
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if(i == row) continue;
            list.add(Arrays.asList(i, col));
        }

        //go horizontal
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if(i == col) continue;
            list.add(Arrays.asList(row, i));
        }

        //go left diag
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for(int j = col - row; j < 8; j++) {
                if(i == row && j == col) continue;
                list.add(Arrays.asList(i, j));
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}

public class Pawn extends Checker {

    public Pawn(String marker, int row, int col, Color color) {
        super(marker, row, col, color);
    }

    @Override
    public List<List<Integer>> getPossibleMoves() {
        List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if(color == Color.RED) {
            list.add(Arrays.asList(row - 1,col - 1));
            list.add(Arrays.asList(row - 1,row + 1));
        } else {
            list.add(Arrays.asList(row + 1,row + 1));
            list.add(Arrays.asList(row + 1,row - 1));
        }
        return list;
    }
}

public interface Movable {
    List<List<Integer>> getPossibleMoves();
}

public class Checkers extends Game {
    private static final int BOARD_SIZE = 8;
    private Board board;
    private List<Player> players;
    private HashMap<Player, String> playerMap;

    public Checkers() {
        board = new Board(BOARD_SIZE, BOARD_SIZE);
        players = new ArrayList<>();
        players.add(new Player("alice"));
        players.add(new Player("bob"));
        playerMap = new HashMap<>();
        playerMap.put(players.get(0), "o");
        playerMap.put(players.get(1), "x");
    }

    @Override
    public void startGame() {
        setBoard();
        boolean playerOneTurn  = true;
        Player currPlayer = null;
        String playerMarker = "";
        while(1 < 2) {
            board.showBoard();
            currPlayer = (playerOneTurn) ? players.get(0) : players.get(1);
            playerMarker = playerMap.get(currPlayer);

            try {
                Piece selectedPiece = getPieceFromInput(currPlayer, playerMarker);
                setNewPiecePosition(currPlayer, selectedPiece);
                playerOneTurn = !playerOneTurn;

            } catch(InvalidStateException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private void setBoard() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
               if((j + i) % 2 == 0) {
                   board.move(new Pawn("o", i, j, Color.BLACK));
               }
            }
        }

        for(int i = BOARD_SIZE - 1; i > BOARD_SIZE - 4; i--) {
            for(int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
                if((j + i) % 2 == 0) {
                    board.move(new Pawn("x", i, j, Color.RED));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Piece getPieceFromInput(Player player, String marker) {
        System.out.println(player.getName() + " please select your piece from row : col");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int row = sc.nextInt();
        int col = sc.nextInt();
        if(board.isCellEmpty(row, col) ) {
            throw new InvalidStateException("You selected a wrong piece");
        } else if(!board.getMarker(row, col).equals(marker)) {
            throw new InvalidStateException("You selected the other players piece");

        }
        return board.getPiece(row, col);
    }

    private void setNewPiecePosition(Player player, Piece piece) {
        List<List<Integer>> moves = ((Checker)piece).getPossibleMoves();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(player.getName() + " Please put your new piece to row : col");
        int row = sc.nextInt();
        int col = sc.nextInt();
        boolean isMoveValid = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < moves.size(); i++) {
            if(row == moves.get(i).get(0) && col == moves.get(i).get(1)){
                isMoveValid = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!isMoveValid) {
            throw new InvalidStateException("Wrong move for selected piece");
        }
        board.removePiece(piece.getRow(), piece.getCol());
        piece.setRow(row);
        piece.setCol(col);
        board.move(piece);
    }
}
```

Here to play the game

```java
public class GameMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game checkers = new Checkers();
        Game tictactoe = new TicTacToe();
        checkers.startGame();
        tictactoe.startGame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might have been a better forum to post the question in https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ but here are a couple opinions I have, some may be wrong, but maybe they'll help (seems like a fun project).

1) I am questioning this design because I could have also created an abstract method vs an interface but this would not be extendable to chess.

You probably want to stick with Interfaces as they'll allow you to expand functionality with less refactoring since you can implement numerous rather than extend one.  With default methods you can also include any common code if you needed.

2) I also did not know how to relate a player to a marker such as x or o in tic tac toe. I use a hashmap to map a player to its marker.

Nothing wrong with how you're doing it at the moment, with regards to assigning a item to the piece.  You might want to look into making it a little better like `Piece implements Movable, Drawable` (back to the interface comment from above).  With regards to where pieces are stored, if you want to keep the pieces within the game and have the game determine all available moves and validity of each piece.  Or you can move them into a Player.Collection if the player or the pieces themselves will be responsible for determining availability on the board.

For example:

```
public TicTacToe() {
    this.players.add(new Player("Player 1", Color.RED, initPieces());
    this.players.add(new Player("Player 2", Color.BLACK, initPieces());
}
```

The Color.RED|BLACK would be applied to the piece when when the player takes control of it.  For example, if you have a game where players can steal other players tokens, the act of adding a new token to a player would automatically update it's Color.  The color is then applied when calling `piece.draw();` or `piece.draw(canvas)` based on what you're doing.

3) I have some code duplication for checkers in which I have an enum color but I also have a variable marker which is kinda the same thing. Not sure how to remedy this.

If using the above comments, you could do a:

```
Collection<Piece<String>> initPieces(String mark) {
    return Arrays.asList(new Piece<>(mark), ...);  // create 5
}

public Person(String name, Color color, Collection<Piece> initialPieces) {
    // for initialPieces set piece color to color
}
```

4) Is it ok to typecast an object? Since board doesn't know what type of piece it has, I have to do this in the Checkers class

If you used the interface Movable when implementing the Piece then you don't need to cast, as both Games/Boards will know:

```
List<List<Integer>> moves = piece.getPossibleMoves();
```

or

```
this.board = new Board<Checker>();
```

which will again ensure that `board.getPeice(x,y)` will return a Checker and no casting is required.  It depends what might occur later in the game and what the rules are.

5) Implementing edge cases based on Game - Checkers where Pawn becomes a King.

In most games there are results that occur after a move takes place.  For example, as you've mentioned:

- Checkers you will remove another players Piece if they were jumped
- Checkers you will King a Pawn if they reach the other side of the board
- Chess you will remove another players piece if they are landed on

In your Checkers game example you'd need to call something after the setNewPiecePosition that handled successful moves.   For checkers you would need this method to:

1. Check the start and the end position and determine if another players Piece was in the middle.  If so you remove that piece from the board (and/or the other players list of pieces).
2. Determine if the player can move again so IF they jumped someone, the same player gets to choose again from the updated list of available moves.
3. Determine if the new position is at the end of the board, then replace the Pawn with a King in the players collection of pieces.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! For using an interface on Piece, would I just return an empty list? Since in tic tac toe there are no moves and Piece is the base class.

Comment: I would argue that there are moves in Tic Tac Toe.  For the first player at the start of the game, all 9 locations are available.  Therefore piece.getAvailableMoves() would return a Collection of 9 locations.  When X is placed at 0,0 then player 2 getAvailableMoves() would return 8 locations.

Comment: Interesting so I am guessing you are putting the responsibility on the player from your previous comment "Or you can move them into a Player.Collection if the player or the pieces themselves will be responsible for determining availability on the board."? I am curious how this would work with checkers

Comment: From your current Checker Pawn example, you already have the Pawn responsible for it's own available moves.  Although the available moves aren't exactly what I would expect.  An available move should already take into account the tile being used.  For example `getAvailableMoves(board)` would look at the current location, `check 1,1 (my own Piece) no dice` then check `1, -1 (opponent) 2, -2 (free) jump move.`  Tic Tac Toe would be the same `getAvailableMoves(board)` return all open spots.

Comment: Oh it does that already, since the pieces are placed they have their initial location on the board which then pawn references its current location and returns the possible moves based on the color.